# PowerShell script to move files and folders including subfolders from one location to another older than x days

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-1.0

I developed a PowerShell script, and it's working absolutely fine. The only challenge is the files in the subfolders are not getting moved to the destination.

```
get-childitem -Path "\\servername\location" |
    where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-31)} |
    move-item -destination "C:\Dumps"
```

I am unable to customize the script further.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the `-Recurse` option on the `Get-ChildItem` command to get through to the files in the sub folders and then move each individually by piping the collection to `Move-Item`

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Test" -Recurse |
  Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-date).AddDays(-31)} |
  Move-Item -destination "C:\Dumps"
```

Here's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Musaab. The -Recursive doesn't seem to be working. Can you help further ?

Comment: Are you sure the files meet the where-object clause?
I'll update my answer with a screenshot to illustrate how I'm using the -Recursive option. Check it and let me know what I'm I doing different.

Comment: Hello Musaab...I have come across a new challenge now....with the above script...i am trying to schedule this in windows task scheduler (windows 2008 server X84 bit) on schedule the powershell script isn't working...manually running on batch it does the job. can you please help me further...I have placed lot of arguments to make that run..but nothing worked out....please help...

Comment: Have a look at my answer to this question, it will probably help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14635995/running-powershell-script-as-scheduled-task/14644128#14644128

Comment: This doesn't preserve the folder structure

Answer (score 21):

Don't waste your time trying to re-invent `robocopy` in PowerShell.

```
robocopy \\servername\location C:\Dumps /e /mov /minage:31
```

Comment: This script is copying files to the destination and only from the main path. I would like to include the subfolders as well. I want to move them to another location.

Comment: Use `/s` to recurse into subfolders. Use `/e` (instead of `/s`) to include empty subfolders as well. What do you mean by "another location"? Do you not want to preserve the folder structure? In that case you could stick with PowerShell (with the `-Recursive` option, as @Musaab mentioned). This approach will put you at risk of data loss due to overwritten files, though.

Comment: Thanks Ansgar....your robocopy script did the job i wanted and more over I was able to build one more script for another usage.

Comment: robocopy does the move **by copying file bit by bit and then deleting it**. Instead just moving it quickly. Hence is much slower. This behavior cannot be turned off.

Comment: @peterson How would you move files between different filesystems without doing that?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers this behaviour occurs when moving on same filesystem, within folders. Because afaik nothing else uses this strange and slow approach, it's worth to mention

Answer (score 8):

Simplification of the above


`robocopy A:\ B:\ /MIR /minage:31`


Where 
A:\ is your source
B:\ is your destination

Answer (score 0):

I needed a quick one liner to move all data off one drive onto another. This worked perfectly for me:

Get-ChildItem "E:" -Recurse | Move-Item -Destination "G:"